# How to loop over bpy.data.objects if i need to rename objects?

Tags: scripting

I'm feeling kinda stupid here. I'm trying to rename a bunch of objects in my scene using a for loop over bpy.data.objects, like so:

```
slots = ["decl", "hair", "hand", "head", "jack", "sus", "task", "uppr", "lowr"]
arms = []
ind = 0
for j, o in enumerate(bpy.data.objects):
    if o.type == "ARMATURE":
        print(str(j) + " " + o.name)
        o.name = slots[ind]
        arms.append(o)
        ind += 1
        if (ind >= len(slots)): break
```

but it appears that the list of objects is being sorted dynamically by object name, and so i end up iterating over the object i already renamed as it gets moved further up the list. How do i make sure that i iterate over each object and only once if i need to change their names?

Comment: have u tried to iterate over the objects using index? `for idx in range(len(bpy.data.objects)): obj=bpy.data.objects[idx]`

Comment: Yeah, but the result is same. Here's the output i see in console: ```0 decl_000_u
2 decl_001_u
3 decl_002_u
4 hair
6 hair_001_u
7 hair_002_u
8 hair_003_u
9 hair_004_u
10 hair_005_u``` The one at index 4 is renamed decl_001_u

Comment: ah then it looks like the only way is to loop and store them in a separate list. and then iterate through that list using index/range to do the renames. that should work.

Comment: That did worked, yes. Thanks. Still i'm wondering if there is supposed to be a way to "pause" auto-sorting somehow temporarily.

Comment: i don't think there is and ever should be such a "pause" function. but there could be another loop rename way thats not altered by the auto alphebetic sorting.

Comment: You can't (or shouldn't) iterate over a list that you're also modifying. Maybe try re-creating it with `for j, o in enumerate([ob for ob in bpy.data.objects]):`